# How to prove the Bayes formula below?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

$$
p(W,H,β|V) = \frac{p(V|W,H)  p(W|β)  p(H|β)  p(β)}{p(V)}
$$

I have tried a lot but I cannot prove this formula. The paper is:

- Ioannis Psorakis, I, Roberts, S, Ebden, M, & Sheldon, B. (2011). Overlapping community detection using Bayesian non-negative matrix factorization.  PHYSICAL REVIEW E 83, 066114. ([pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vMDQotvcP1Mwhd29JyHvH5trkxAoS5Wm/view?usp=sharing))

which gives a graphical model structure for the variables in question as:
[image: V depends on H and W, which separately depend on \beta, which depends on fixed a and b]

Comment: I'm a bit simple, but it seems like there's some information missing here about how $W, H, \beta, V$ relate to each other in terms of dependence/independence.

Comment: This is a formula from a research paper my professor gave me :)

Comment: Can you provide a citation for the paper? Can you provide some of the contextual information around it, especially "how W,H,β,V relate to each other in terms of dependence/independence" as @KitterCatter requests?

Comment: if we follow the bayes formula, i think the first term on the right hand side should be p(V | W,H,β) @gung

Answer (score 2):

According to the paper and the graphical model (Fig. 1) which specifies dependencies/independencies between the variables, authors didn't use the Bayes formula. They used the definition of the conditional probability.

The Eq. (2) stems from Eq. (1) by using the conditional probability definition. The Eq. (1) is the joint distribution over all model variables.

If you look at the graphical model, the dependencies are specified by it. Just use the basic result of dependencies to read the graph and write the joint probability.

Comment: Oh, graphical model. Sorry  because i am just undergraduate and i have not learned  graphical model yet. I think i have good reason to learn graphical model now. By

Comment: By the way, Tks a lot for your help.

Comment: The graphical model basics are very easy and fast to learn. In your case, all you need is to understand what is a graphical model and the chain rule when writing the joint probability + conditional probability definition. There are good videos on YouTube that explain these basics.

Comment: By the way, if you are into graphical models seriously and you want to implement/customize the models, I suggest to learn the Infer.NET package (C#) or PyMC3 (Python). Both are great projects. I learned about graphical models there.

Comment: which book should i use to learn graphical model. I have background on math so highly technical book is not a big problem.

Comment: And a course on grphical model. Would you recommend some courses for me? Tks .

Comment: I suggest to start with Christopher Bishop "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" book. If you don't have it, you can check his paper & video on "model-based machine learning". He explains the main concepts very well. After that, you should be able to find the references yourself. And remember, this is called "probabilistic programming". I took the EdX MIT course on probabilistic inference and reasoning. The course was pretty tough (for me) but I learned a ton.

Comment: Check out also Chris Bishop's (and others) online book http://mbmlbook.com/ It is fairly compact but it introduces the application side and practice with Infer.NET. If you decide to give Infer.NET a try, check out their great 101 document. The forum is moderated by Tom Minka, he helped me a lot (make sure to do your home work before posting).

Comment: Great, I have read some paper about bayesian ML of Tom Minka, and impressed a lot about his knowledge on bayesian statistic and application in other related area.

Answer (score 1):

The formula can be proved under the assumptions that $V$ and $\beta$ are independent and that $W$ and $H$ are *conditionally* independent given $\beta$, which assumptions might well be deducible from the graphical model in the paper (to which I don't have access). 
\begin{align}
p(W,H,\beta\mid V) &= \frac{p(W,H,\beta,V)}{p(V)}
& {\scriptstyle{\text{definition of conditional probability}}}\\
&= \frac{p(V\mid W,H,\beta)\cdot p(W,H,\beta)}{p(V)}
& {\scriptstyle{\text{conditional probability def. used backwards}}}\\
&= \frac{p(V\mid W,H)\cdot p(W,H,\beta)}{p(V)}
& {\scriptstyle{\text{assuming that}~V~\text{is independent of}}~\beta}\\
&= \frac{p(V\mid W,H)\cdot p(W,H\mid\beta)\cdot p(\beta)}{p(V)}
& {\scriptstyle{\text{conditional probability def. used backwards again}}}\\
&= \frac{p(V\mid W,H)\cdot p(W\mid\beta)\cdot p(H\mid \beta)\cdot p(\beta)}{p(V)}
& {\scriptstyle{\text{assuming}~W~\text{and}~H~\text{conditionally independent given}~\beta}}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Note that your assumption in the third line is actually that $V$ is conditionally independent of $\beta$ given $W$ and $H$, not marginally independent. This is the case in the graphical model given in the paper: $V$ depends only on $W$ and $H$, which each depend (separately) on $\beta$.